# when pass string variable to jasonparser jsonobject returns null

Tags: json, groovy

To read the json file I have created below method in groovy. I am calling it from another class.

```
class WUPage{

    @Shared
    String fileContents ;
    def jsonSlurper ;
    def jsonObject ;

     public String getValueFromJsonFile(String fileName, String jsonKey){
        fileContents = new File(fileName).getText('UTF-8')
        jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        jsonObject = jsonSlurper.parseText(fileContents)

        println " Json Key from method  is : " + jsonObject.jsonKey
        println " Json Key hardecoded  is : " + jsonObject.pipe.id

        return jsonObject.jsonKey

    }
}
```

When I am calling this method from another class I am passing file name and the key to it like below

```
getValueFromJsonFile(jsonFIleName, "pipe.id")
```

I am getting below output

```
 Json Key from method  is : null
 Json Key hardecoded  is : [India]
```

From above output second line is correct when key is hardcoded. It seems it's not recognizing key coming from method parameter.

Can you please help me on this.

Json File is :

```
{
  "source": [
    {
      "id": "manish",
      "type": "csv",
      "path": "/home/surya/f1.txt",
      "delimiter": ",",
      "tableName": "table1",
      "schema": "f1,f2,f3,f4,f5"
    }
  ],
  "pipe": [
    {
      "id": "India",
      "sql": "select f1,f2,f5 from table1"
    }
  ],
  "sinks": [
    {
      "id": "output1",
      "type": "aaa",
      "path": "/home/surya/out",
      "format": "json"
    }

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the dot in the key name is not doing what you expected. You didn't show your JSON data in the original post, but I can deduce that there is a top-level object "pipe" that contains an `id` key. Groovy can't magically know this, so it applies the entire parameter as a top-level key, not as compound deep keys.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest me any other way to do this. Because my requirement is to pass the json file location and the key for which value is needed, so that I can effectively use that to get the values for particular key from Json on runtime basis in a test case

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to always get the key `jsonKey` from that map.

```
def json = [a: [b: 42]] // just some map, but that's what your JsonSlurper result is

def key = 'a' // start with a simple key

println json.key // wont work, because groovy will access the key `key`
// => null

println json."$key" // works, now
// => [b:42]

key = 'a.b'
println json."$key" // wont work, because you can not access recursive keys like that
// => null
```

So at that point you have to decide, what to do and how comples your path there can become and what's the source of your path (e.g. is is always a string from somewhere else or is this for developer convenience).

- You can `Eval` a string
- You can "split" the path at `.` and then reduce this list over the map
- Instead of a string pass in a Closure, that accesses the data

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest me any other way to do this. Because my requirement is to pass the json file location and the key for which value is needed, so that I can effectively use that to get the values for particular key from Json on runtime basis in a test case.

Comment: I suggested the ways to do it in the paragraph after the code examples.