# convert string to yaml path in groovy jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a yaml file loaded from `readYaml` into a variable from jenkins pipeline utility steps.

let's say this is my yaml file loaded into var `myYaml`:

```
---
trunk: interest
put: stepped
wonder: true
oldest: surrounded
ship: false
heading: false
very:
  - fight: hunter
    character: true
    hidden: tin
wealth: lesson
finish: sense
  - word
  - tree
  - nickel
```

normally you would reference a yaml property with dot notation as so,

```
echo(myYaml.very.character)
output: true
```

I am trying to take a path that is already as a string, and turn that into a path I can reference yaml with.

```
myStringPath = "very.character"
myYaml.myStringPath
```

I see a lot of examples of this in javascript, but I can't seem to find an elegant way in groovy or jenkins groovy. Any recommendations?

Comment: Wouldn't the result be `[true]` since you are using the implicit spread operator?  `very` is a list of maps.

Comment: yeah, sorry. Either way I think you get the idea. Referencing a path from a string.

Comment: You have to split the path at `.` and reduce over your map.  if you want to have the implicit spread operator, you have to be definesive about navigating down (e.g. if the node is a list, use the spread operator, if the node is a map go down, otherwise just stop). If you like to live dangerous, you an use `Eval` to get the value out. I'd say this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042953/when-pass-string-variable-to-jasonparser-jsonobject-returns-null/49044721